# How to handle null ArrayList while starting another activity

Tags: android, arraylist

I have series of images, when pressed by user should start a new activity and pass some data (ArrayList of custom object). ArrayList of custom object is initialized based on user input. Now, I am facing problem that when user has not still given input for ArrayList and clicks any of Image, it shows application get stops. I tried to handle it through try and catch block but it does not work. The whole flow works fine when ArrayList is not empty.[Image to have look at App (on Top, series of images are there which gets populated basis user selection from a list and then user can click any image of them)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUDpl.png)

Find relevant codes below:

Relevant Block from MainActivity:

```
 @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

            holder.imageView.setImageResource(horizontalList.get(position).imageId);
            holder.txtview.setText(horizontalList.get(position).txt);

            holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override

                public void onClick(View v) {


                    String list = horizontalList.get(position).txt.toString();
                    List<Coupon> couponList = new ArrayList<>();
                    try {
                        for (Place place : allOffers) {
                            Coupon coupon = new Coupon(place.mPlace, place.mOffer, place.mImage, list);
                            couponList.add(coupon);
                        }

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, list, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intentCat = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CategoryOffersActivity.class);
                        intentCat.putExtra("Category", (Serializable) couponList);
                        startActivity(intentCat);

                    } catch(Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"List is Empty",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                }

            });

        }
```

New Activity which gets started when image is clicked by user:

```
public class CategoryOffersActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements PlaceAdapter.AdapterInterface,Serializable {

    ListView catListView;
    List<Place> catOffers = new ArrayList<Place>();
    PlaceAdapter catPlaceAdapter;
    Place [] catPlaces;
    List <Coupon> listCoupon=new ArrayList<Coupon>();
    TextView mHeader;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_categoryoffers);
        catListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.catListView);
        mHeader=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.categoryName);

        if (getIntent() != null) {
            listCoupon = (ArrayList<Coupon>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Category");
            if (listCoupon != null) {
                ArrayList<Place> placeList = new ArrayList<>();
                for(Coupon coupon : listCoupon) {
                    Place place=new Place(coupon.mPlace,coupon.mOffer,coupon.mImage);
                    placeList.add(place);
                }
                catPlaces=placeList.toArray(new Place[placeList.size()]);
                mHeader.setText(listCoupon.get(0).mItemClicked+" Coupon History");
                catPlaceAdapter = new PlaceAdapter(CategoryOffersActivity.this, R.layout.row, catPlaces, this);
                if (catListView != null) {
                    catListView.setAdapter(catPlaceAdapter);
                }

            }
        }


    }





    @Override
    public void buttonPressed() {
        // some action
    }

}
```

Comment: if(arraylist.size()>0){
//arraylist is not empty
}

Comment: This is not clear, what is the ArrayList that is null ? There is instances that are not declare in your code, so hard to see what those are and when you initialise those. Creating a [mcve] should help you with this. But of course, your question is simple, just check if the instance is null or initialize the instance in the create method

Comment: @Redman it solved my issue. Just curious, instead of that earlier I used if(arraylist!=null) why it did not work?

Comment: Because a list can be initialize and empty.

Comment: Please don't post your answer in the comments if it is already answer by someone support them if it was helpful for the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ((listCoupon != null)&&(listCoupon.size()>0))
```

Also check for array size